# How to set navigator.webdriver to false in selenium chrome by using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set this argument to false in chrome. IN firefox we can do this `profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)`
How can i perform this on chrome.
Any help would be appreciated.